# Rails validation :if => Proc.new or lambda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda

I have found that in all examples (include rails documentation) that I have seen for the :if option of validation methods uses Proc.new instead of lambda, for example

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :if => Proc.new{|f| .... } # why not lambda here?
end
```

is there any reason for this? 
As far as I know, lambda

1. Is more strict with arguments.
2. Also return statement in lambda block returns from the block, not from calling function.

Both seems to be desirable behavior for :if option mentioned above, is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Both seems to be desirable behavior for :if option mentioned above, is there anything I am missing?

I'm guessing that:

It's more desirable to allow Procs as they don't care about the number of arguments. So I could easily write any of the below:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :if => Proc.new{|f| f.display_name.blank? }    # I care about 'f' here as I need it to check something.
```

... and:

```
validates_presence_of :secret_sauce, :if => Proc.new{ MyApp::REQUIRE_SECRET_SAUCE }    # I don't care about any arguments being passed in.
```

This may seem like a minor thing, but I guess it adds to the flexibility.

Comment: Thank you Jits, I think it's pretty rare that I'd use a :if option without the model instance, in that case I can still just put |dummy| there. So I'd go with lambda, but you explanation makes sense.

Comment: But do we really need to pass the instance as an argument? If I understand correctly, code in the block (either in Proc.new or lambda) will just be evaulated when needed and it is possible to write something like this:

    has_many :associated_objects

    before_save :do_something, if: -> { associated_objects.empty? }

Notice that I skipped argument { |instance| instance.associated_... }