# Rails - one model, 2 kinds of validation rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, attributes

In an app I have 3 types of contact forms - in the model - the attributes `:aaa, :bbb, :ccc` belongs to the second contact form, the previous attributes belongs to the first contact form.

```
class Message

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :body, :aaa, :bbb, :ccc

  validates :name, :email, :body, :aaa, :bbb, :ccc, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

What I am trying to do: I am looking for a way, how to validate attributes for the respective contact forms, specifically:

- the first contact form contains attributes: `:name, :email, :body`, which I need to validate
- the second contract form contains attributes: `:aaa, :bbb, :ccc, :email`, which I need to validate

How to do that? How to distinguish, which attributes belongs to which form and validate them?

Comment: what about the `if` argument & `proc` for the validation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232099/rails-validation-if-proc-new-or-lambda might interest you

Comment: How do you distinguish whether any given Message object is form 1 or form 2?

Answer (score 0):

If there are 3 types of contract forms why not make them 3 separate classes?
If for some erason you still want to keep it in one class, you can do it using 'with_options' magic:

```
with_options :if => :is_form_1? do |p|
  p.validates_presence_of :attr1
  p.validates_presence_of :attr2
  p.validates_presence_of :attr3
end

with_options :if => :is_form_2? do |p|
  p.validates_presence_of :attr4
  p.validates_presence_of :attr5
  p.validates_presence_of :attr6
end

def is_form_1?
  #some logic
end

def is_form_2?
  #some logic
end
```

Still, I don't like the idea of keeping it in one class.

Comment: Because I would like to keep it in one. This is the latest option to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you think about this in behavioural rather than implementation terms. You mention there are three contact forms, but what is the underlying use that you're putting each one to? You shouldn't be thinking about *forms* when you're setting up your model.

That having been said, you can achieve what you want using [the validation_scopes gem](https://github.com/gtd/validation_scopes). Using validation_scopes, you can define sets of validation rules that you can treat independently. In your controllers, you can then check whichever set of validation rules apply to the context (i.e. which form the user has filled in).

In your model you can set up validation scopes named for each form (or better, named for the context in a way that has semantic value, but I don't know enough about your app to know what the contexts are), like this:

```
validation_scope :form_one_errors do |vs|
  validates :name, :body, :presence => true
end

validation_scope :form_two_errors do |vs|
  validates :aaa, :bbb, :ccc, :presence => true
end
```

Since email needs to be validated in both contexts, you can just set it up as a normal validation (as per your code in the question).

Then in the controller for, say, form one, you can check the scope to see if there are any errors for that context. Note that you have to check the errors for the validation scope separately for the regular validation errors.

```
if !message.valid?
  # Do something with message.errors
elsif message.has_form_one_errors?
  # Do something with message.form_one_errors
else 
  # All good
end
```

Comment: Did you check out validation_scopes, user984621? I've added some code examples to my answer to make it clearer how you can use it.